# Using Meteor for a Tokbox Video Application

Tags: meteor, opentok, tokbox

Does anyone happen to know any Meteor developers who also have experience utilizing Tokbox Video Streaming API? We have a web app that is 90% completed and we are looking for help fully integrating our video functionality.  Any referrals/guidance/direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post a minimal Meteor app with Tokbox that you can't get working, we could try to help you through it. Once that works, you could integrate those learnings into your real app